# Error with implicitly typed variables

Tags: c#, linq

When assigning a linq selection to an implicitly typed local variable "var" i receive the 
following error.

**`Error :Cannot assign method group to an implicitly-typed local variable`**

at

```
root : var mailgroup = emails.Where(p =>IsValidFormat(p.Value)).Select;
```

Dictionary of elements

```
        Dictionary<int, string> emails = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        emails.Add(1, "Marry@yahoo.com");
        emails.Add(2, "Helan@gmail.com");
        emails.Add(3, "Rose");
        emails.Add(4, "Ana");
        emails.Add(5, "Dhia@yahoo.com");
        Dictionary<int, string> dc = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

How to correct it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Processing lambdas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590805/asp-net-processing-lambdas)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What are you expecting it to do? You probably want to make an actual method call there, such as:

```
var mailgroup = emails.Where(p =>IsValidFormat(p.Value))
                      .Select(p => p.Value);
```

Or if you just want the key/value pairs, you can just use:

```
var mailgroup = emails.Where(p =>IsValidFormat(p.Value));
```

and remove the "Select" entirely.

If you *do* just want the values (as per the first code snippet) I'd suggest using:

```
var mailgroup = emails.Values.Where(p =>IsValidFormat(p));
```

Without any brackets, your reference to "Select" is a method group - the kind of thing you'd convert to a delegate, e.g.

```
Func<int> x = SomeMethod; // Where SomeMethod is declared as "int SomeMethod()"
```

It doesn't really make sense to use `Select` as method group in this case, although it *is* just about feasible...

Comment: @geneliaa: I suspect you didn't have enough reputation. Try again now.

Comment: Wow. I registered my first vote to my favorite C# author(C# in depth).

Comment: Did you just give someone an upvote just so he could give you one? I think that's taking rep-whoring way too far.

Comment: @Joren: Just how much rep do you believe a vote gives me at this time of day? It's about 14 hours too late...

Comment: I have no idea what timezone you're in. I'm sorry for jumping to conclusions about your intentions, but this just looked way weird.

Comment: @Joren: My time zone is irrelevant. The reputation cap is applied in UTC.

Answer (score 9):

You're missing `()` after `Select`. As a result, what's being assigned to the variable is a reference to the Select method, which the compiler refers to as a 'method group'.

Incidentally, based on the code that you've posted I don't think that you need the trailing `.Select()` at all.

Comment: There are no parameterless overloads for Select though - he'll need to put *something* in there.

Comment: (An empty select statement *isn't* valid.)

Comment: Yeah... I double-checked and removed that statement while you were posting your comment.